# -moz-column-span: all; – completely ignored?

Tags: firefox, css

Testing in various versions of Firefox new and old it seems that column-span in CSS3 is ignored completely?

Even the simple demo on quirksmode fails in firefox:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Has this ever worked? I'm having trouble finding anything related online. Surely it should work if there is a prefix for the rule (`-moz-column-span`)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your reference from the W3C: [`column-span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-multicol-20010118/#column-span)

`-moz` is only the Firefox prefix. So you will need use the WebKit and regular declaration as well.

It should look something like this:

```
.pullquote {
    -moz-column-span: 2;
    -webkit-column-span: 2;
    column-span: 2;
}
```

Single Column is not the worst thing as a fallback, but IE users might not be super into this. See more info at the [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn) website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man, but yeah, doesn't work when tested. Does it work for you in Firefox?

For instance, the following demo found on a google search - http://vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/multi-column/

Works in safari (http://cl.ly/3b3W3a0B391R3q1A1G2u)
Fails in FF latest version (http://cl.ly/2v2f3Y2e1L0y2C1a3x02)

Comment: Yeah. Looks like in your first link it says "not supported" next to column-span stuff, but at this link it looks like it is a candidate and but not yet supported by Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/column-span).

Comment: I'm sure they will probably use -moz- when they do pick it up though.

Comment: Just another major point, here, guys.  MDN states that the correct syntax for this does not allow an element to span only a specific number of columns, so the value can never be a number... its either you span 'all' columns, or 'none'... 'inherit' is also possible, but will, obviously, also resolve to either 'all' or 'none'.

Answer (score 7):

As of today, -moz-column-span and column-span are still not supported by Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

No, `-moz-column-span` and `column-span` are ignored by Firefox. Here is the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616436

Answer (score 1):

CSS column-span is shipped in Firefox 71.
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/12/firefox-71-a-year-end-arrival/

Comment: And all `-moz` prefixes to column properties are officially removed in Firefox 74.0.1.